# Code of sorting 2D array with pointers

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, pointers, selection

I made this code to sort array of pointers, every first element in the array telling us how much elements will be after the first element. Now i want the code to sort(selection sort or any other sort) all line by herself, and keeping the first element(because he telling us the size of the array). the code sorting the fisrt array in the big array of pointers but it's doesn't work at the last array(4,5,6,2,1). help any one? use only pointers in the function's!(not [ and ]) :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define LENGTH 5

void sortArrayAfterFirstPlace(int* pointersArray[], int len);
void printsMatrix(int* pointersArray[], int len);
int main(void)
{
    int firstArr[4] = { 3,9,6,7 };
    int secondArr[3] = { 2, 5, 5 };
    int thirdArr[1] = {0};
    int forthArr[2] = {1,6};
    int fifthArr[5] = {4,5,6,2,1};
    int* arrOfPointers[LENGTH] = { firstArr, secondArr,thirdArr,forthArr,fifthArr };
    sortArrayAfterFirstPlace(arrOfPointers,LENGTH);
    printsMatrix(arrOfPointers,LENGTH);
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}

/*
*/
void sortArrayAfterFirstPlace(int* pointersArray[], int len)
{
    int i = 0,j=0,temp=0;
    int min = 0;
    int lengthOfFirstElement = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        lengthOfFirstElement = *(*(pointersArray + i));
        for (j = i+1; j < lengthOfFirstElement; j++)
        {
            if (*(*(pointersArray + i) + j) > *(*(pointersArray + i) + j + 1))
            {
                temp = *(*(pointersArray + i) + j);
                *(*(pointersArray + i) + j) = *(*(pointersArray + i) + j + 1);
                *(*(pointersArray + i) + j + 1) = temp;
            }
        }

    }
}

/*
*/
void printsMatrix(int* pointersArray[],int len)
{
    int i = 0,j=0;
    int lengthOfFirstElement = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        lengthOfFirstElement = *(*(pointersArray+i));
        for (j = 0; j <lengthOfFirstElement+1; j++)
        {
            printf("%d ", *(*(pointersArray + i) + j));
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you ever heard something about debugging...

Comment: Each array needs two `for` loops (or similar construct) to sort correctly. You want to sort a bunch of arrays, you need three `for` loops (the outer one to "select" the array to be sorted, the inner ones to sort that array). *A good option would be to "hide" the inner loops inside a function.*

Answer (score 0):

You need to be able to access each array to be sorted by looping through the array of pointers to these arrays.

For each array to be sorted you need to create a pointer to it's first element [0] and obtain the number of elements to be sorted from it.
Now you have the information required to loop through each array of numbers and do the sort - the address of the array & the number of elements to be sorted.

When doing a simple bubble sort you do not need two loops - your i & j - as you are only comparing one element in the array to the one following it, but you do need to be able to tell when every element is in order, so a flag that indicates that no elements were swapped can be used in a while loop - when the flag indicates that no elements were swapped on the last run through the array, break out of the while loop.

Here is the outer loop - you will still need to work on the sort within each array, and use the same outer loop approach to do the printing.

```
void sortArrayAfterFirstPlace(int *aofptrs[], int len);
void printout(int *aofptrs[], int len);
int main(void)
{
    int firstArr[4] = { 3,9,6,7 };
    int secondArr[3] = { 2, 5, 5 };
    int thirdArr[1] = {0};
    int forthArr[2] = {1,6};
    int fifthArr[5] = {4,5,6,2,1};
    int *arrOfPointers[LENGTH] = { firstArr, secondArr,thirdArr,forthArr,fifthArr };

    printout(arrOfPointers,LENGTH);
    sortArrayAfterFirstPlace(arrOfPointers,LENGTH);
    printout(arrOfPointers,LENGTH);
}
```

The outer loop of the sort array:

```
void sortArrayAfterFirstPlace(int *aofptrs[], int len)
{
    int arypt, *ptr, numberOfElements, i, sorted, temp;

    /* loop through array of pointers to arrays) */
    for (arypt = 0; arypt < len; arypt++) {
        /* get pointer to array to be sorted */
        ptr = *(aofptrs + arypt);
        /* get number of elements to be sorted from element 0 */
        numberOfElements = *ptr;
        /* sort array */
        while (1) {
            sorted = 1;
            for (i = 1; i < numberOfElements ; i++) {

                // your sort goes here
                // (*(ptr + i) accesses elements in the array
                // (*(ptr + i + 1) access following element in array
                // sorted = 0; if two elements were swapped

            }
            if(sorted == 1) break; // elements were all in order
        }
    }
}
```